# Passing paramaters to initState Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter so I am not sure if this is possible...

I am trying to customise a statefulWidget, building upon the MaterialDesignIcon RaisedButton.

I would like to simply pass in two parameters on the instantiation of the raisedButton.

So when I create the RaisedButton I can do something like below.....

```
RaisedButton(backgroundColor: Colors.grey, text: 'Press me')
```

Please see the code I am trying to make work below.

```
class CustomRaisedButton extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  CustomRaisedButtonState createState() => CustomRaisedButtonState();
}

 void buttonPressed() {
   print('A FUNCTION WOULD GO HERE');
 }

class CustomRaisedButtonState extends State<CustomRaisedButton> {
  var _backgroundColor = Colors.transparent;
  var _text = String;
  var _hoverColor = Colors.transparent;

  @override
  void initState(backgroundColor, text) { < ---- // Can I put the parameters required here?
    super.initState();

    this._backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    this._text = text;

     if (_backgroundColor != Colors.grey) {
      _textColor = Colors.white;
    }
    if (_backgroundColor == Colors.grey) {
      _hoverColor = Colors.black54;
     }
    if (_backgroundColor == Colors.red) {
      _hoverColor = Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
    }
    if (_backgroundColor == Colors.lightGreen) {
      _hoverColor = Colors.green;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: buttonPressed,
      color: _backgroundColor,
      textColor: Colors.black,
      disabledColor: Colors.black38,
      disabledTextColor: _textColor,
      disabledElevation: 4,
      elevation: 4,
      hoverColor: _hoverColor,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text('$_text', style: CustomTextStyle.display1(context))
    );
  }
}
```

This may seem a stupid question as I know you can access those properties in the parameters of the custom widget instantiation anyway. But I would like to change the different properties of the button depending on the backgroundColor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically you just make the `State` access the properties of its `widget` member.  Since the widget is *immutable*, it shouldn't matter if when or how those properties are passed along.  That is, your `initState` function could just as easily use `widget.backgroundColor` and `widget.text` instead of having parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the widgets properties in a stateful widget using `widget.`:

```dart
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final String data;
  const ExampleWidget({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleWidgetState createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {

  String text; 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    text = widget.data.substring(0,2).toUpperCase();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no question is stupid! :D. There is not this possibility, initState doesn't receive any parameters. But as you said yourself you can always access the Widget properties.

What do you want to accomplish that you are not able to using the widgets properties approach?

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the initState, as you can hopefully see, I am changing the textColor and hoverColor of the element based upon what the backgroundColor  is set to on creation. In the very last line of the code I am also trying to globally set the textStyle, so that I do not have to set it every time I create a button.

Comment: The _backgroundColor variable is created and instantiated before the initState. So you can freely use it and the others variable on the initState withou passing they as parameters

Comment: If I weren't to put those variables in the widget however, is there someway of creating a getter, to find out what the value of a property is, when the object is created?

So, for instance when I create a button ````RaisedButton( color: green)```` in my main.dart file.

Can I do anything automatically with this "green" property back in the customButtonClass.dart

Comment: What you can do (i don't know if thats what you want) is creating the variables on the CustomRaisedButton and not on the CustomRaisedButtonState, and on the CustomRaisedButtonState you could acess those variables with the widget.<var-name>. Doing that you can get the values that you want